# A service or something to redirect a URL to a local file

Tags: web-apps, google-apps, hyperlink, url

**Context**

I want to insert hyperlinks to local files (of form file:///path/to/file) into a Google Doc. But validation there do not allow it (it demands http/https URL scheme).

I understand that a local file reference most likely will be useless on other machines from where I could open the google doc and which don't have the local file. It's ok for my case.

**Question**

I assume there may be a web application that would redirect a request to the corresponding local (to my machine) file. Is there such service?

*Example*: Ideally, I'd love to find a service, let's say its domain is tofile.com, so that it would redirect http://tofile.com/some/path to file:///some/path . This way I would insert http://tofile.com/some/path hyperlink into Google Doc, and when I click it,  /some/path file from my machine will be opened in my browser.

Comment: Local to where?   To google?  To your hard drive?  To mine?

Comment: The closest thing i can think of is https://ifttt.com, you can make any web request and let it do actions but won't answer because i don't really understand the task

Comment: @Lynob, I was not able to find something appropriate at ifttt.com . I've extended the question. Does it help?

Comment: Related: https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/153706/why-local-links-are-disabled-by-default-in-modern-browsers

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2087894/can-google-chrome-open-local-links

Answer (score 1):

This does not exist because it is a **major** security risk. A Google doc in the cloud would suddenly be able to access a local file.

Browsers just won't allow it; a link in your browser cannot reach out to a local file.